# Type comparison not returning expected result

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, comparison, types

I am using the following code to compare types so that a DataContractSerializer will re-initialize with the correct type if necessary.

```
    private void InitializeSerializer(Type type)
    {
        if (this.serializer == null)
        {
            this.serializer = new DataContractSerializer(type);
            this.typeToSerialize = type;
        }
        else
        {
            if (this.typeToSerialize != null)
            {
                if (this.typeToSerialize.GetType() != type.GetType())
                {
                    this.serializer = new DataContractSerializer(type);
                    this.typeToSerialize = type;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

For some reason when I compare the two types the result is always true and I never enter the final 'if' statement and re-initialize my serialiser.

I can set a break point at the comparison and clearly see that the two types are 
`List<Host>` (this.typeToSerialize.GetType()) and 
`Post` (type.GetType())

Both Host and Post share a common ancestor but that shouldn't be affecting the result.

Comment: If you are using Visual Studio have you tried sticking a breakpoint on this line in the debugger and when the program breaks here running the two methods in the Immediate window to see what output is produced?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are calling `GetType()` on a `System.Type`. This will return a `System.Type` object that describes  `System.Type` itself.

This makes the code

```
if (this.typeToSerialize.GetType() != type.GetType())
{
   ...
}
```

equivalent to:

```
if(typeof(System.Type) != typeof(System.Type)) // Always false
{
   ... // Never enters here
}
```

I'm guessing what you really mean to be doing is:

```
if(typeToSerialize != type)
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: Indeed, if you lose the two .GetType() calls in the condition it should work correctly.

Comment: Brilliant. I knew it was something simple. Thanks for the underlying explanation too.

Answer (score 3):

```
if (this.typeToSerialize != type)
```

looks more appropriate

Answer (score 3):

It looks as though you are comparing the types of two Type objects. I think you would need to compare the type objects themselves.

```
this.typeToSerialize != type
```

Both this.typeToSerialize.GetType() and type.GetType() will return typeof(Type) (the same object).